# how to add a label in datagrid area in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which populates list of files for conversion. 
I can add files

1. By selecting files from folder through button click
2. By drag and drop files to the datagrid area

I have done with these functionalities,but now we have a requirement to show the second option, "drag and drop files here" in the empty datagrid area initially. Once files are added this text should disappear.

My question is how to add a label or textblock in datagrid area?

Comment: It can be on top (define it last in xaml). Another option is don't show empty `DataGrid` at all, show that `TextBlock` instead, once user drag/add something: hide `TextBlock` and show `DataGrid`.

Comment: I tried this option, but we need to show an empty datagrid area to drop files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to use a `VisualBrush` to draw a text on DataGrid background. Since text should be displayed only for empty grid, I set Background in Trigger for `HasItems` property

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <TextBlock Text="Drag'n'Drop"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```